# Django GenericForeignKey update

Tags: django, django-migrations, generic-foreign-key

I am trying to convert a ForeignKey to GenericForeignKey in django. I plan to do this in three migrations, mig1, mig2, mig3.

Migration 1 (mig1) has the following code

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name'),
        ('post_service', '0008_auto_20180802_1112'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='comment',
            name='content_type',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='contenttypes.ContentType'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='comment',
            name='object_id',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Migration 2 (mig2) has the following code

```
def change_posts_to_generic_key_comment(apps, schema_editor):
    Comment  = apps.get_model('post_service', 'Comment')
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    comments = Comment.objects.using(db_alias).all()
    for comment in comments:
        Comment.objects.filter(id=comment.id).update(content_object=comment.post)

def reverse_change_posts_to_generic_key_comment(apps, schema_editor):
    Comment  = apps.get_model('post_service', 'Comment')
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    comments = Comment.objects.using(db_alias).all()
    for comment in comments:
        Comment.objects.filter(id=comment.id).update(content_object=)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('post_service', '0009_auto_20180802_1623'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(change_posts_to_generic_key_comment, reverse_change_posts_to_generic_key_comment),
    ]
```

I tried to use both update and direct assignment of object

`comment.content_object = content.post` followed by `comment.save()`

none of them seems to work. How do i update generic foreign key field.

One method is to manually set `content_type` and `object_id`. Is there any better way of doing this?

**EDIT: Comment Model**

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Fields for generic relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

Comment: I came across this today. My theory is that something's happening because the model instances aren't *true* instances of the model class, but instances of the class returned by `apps.get_model`, which is a representation of the model class at some point in history. But TBH, I've got no idea. I hope to look into this further when I have more time.

Was able to work around by setting `content_type_id` and `object_id` directly in the migration.

Comment: I have the same issue in my view, how did you update the GenericForeignKey field in Django?

Comment: @codinginquarantine i ran a function which fetches all the items in a model and assigns each of them manually in a loop, and assign content_type and object_id then save it, but it is very inefficient. At least that is how I think I did it back then.

Answer (score 5):

I had problems updating generic foreign keys in the migration. If I tried setting the key directly to the object, it did not set anything on save (because it did not recognise the GenericForeignKey), and if I tried setting content_type and object_id I got errors about content_type must be set to ContentType (which was what I was doing).

In the end I created a management command which was run from the migration as follows:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
from django.core.management import call_command

def populate_discounts(apps, schema_editor):
    """
    I could not get special to update as a generic foriegn key in the 
    migration. Do it as a one off management command
    """
    call_command('initialise_credit_specials')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name'),
        ('money', '0068_auto_20190123_0147'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='invoicecredit',
            name='special_id',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='invoicecredit',
            name='special_type',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='contenttypes.ContentType'),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(populate_discounts)
    ]
```

and my management command was pretty simple:

```
from django.core.management.base import CommandError, BaseCommand    
from money.models import InvoiceCredit, PromotionCode, Sale


class Command(BaseCommand):
    """
    Report how much we need to refund at the end of the financial year
    """
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('updating discounts')
        # first promotions 
        for pc in PromotionCode.objects.all():
            ics = InvoiceCredit.objects.filter(
                desc__contains=pc.code
                )
            for ic in ics.all():
                ic.special = pc
                ic.save()
                print('invoice credit %d updated with %s' % (ic.id, ic.special.code))

        # Then sales
        for sale in Sale.objects.all():
            ics = InvoiceCredit.objects.filter(
                desc__startswith=Sale.desc,
                invoice__booking__tour_date__tour=sale.tour_combinations.first().base_tour
                )
            for ic in ics.all():
                ic.special = sale
                ic.save()
                print('invoice credit %d updated with sale %d' % (ic.id, sale.id))
```

Comment: "if I tried setting content_type and object_id I got errors about content_type must be set to ContentType (which was what I was doing)" —— For who’s wondring the same problem, I figured out. Make sure you import using `ContentType = apps.get_model("contenttypes", "ContentType")` instead of python module `import`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to use filter and update here. You have the object already.

```
for comment in comments:
    comment.content_object = comment.post
    comment.save()
```

Comment: I am trying to phaseout `post`  Foreign key to `content_type` GenericForeignKey . So I need to map all the foreign-key mapping from post to GenericForeignkey. generic foreign key doesn't support update or direct assignment.

Comment: What? Yes it does, otherwise how could you set it? Maybe you should show your models.

Comment: I have added the `Comment` model in question.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand what you are saying. You certainly can assign directly to content_object, and the code I've given works fine.

Comment: Hmm, even i think it should work, but i don't know why it doesn't work, updated data didn't get reflected after migrations, so i manually set `content_type` and `object_id` it works.

Comment: I've also experienced generic foreign keys not being saved in migrations. I'm not sure why